# RHEL Clones (Centos, Scientific, CERN) network installation on XenServer 6.2

Tags: redhat, xen, xenserver, kickstart, scientific-linux

I'm trying to install a Scientific Linux CERN 6 guest on XenServer 6.2 through the network with PXE Booting but it hangs in the message:

```
mounting /tmp as tmpfs... done
```

I'm not using the most equivalent template (the CentOS 6 template) to install this VM, since we want to install it through our PXE Server, because it gets our kickstart file and create the VM with our necessities, and using the template there's no option to boot from the network. So the "Other Install Media" template was used.

I've tried other RHEL based distros, like clean Scientific Linux 6 (not the CERN flavour) and CentOS 6. All of the three got same problem.

Other distros, like Debian and Ubuntu installs fine with this method, and even the older 5.x version of Scientific Linux installs fine.

I think there's something related with the Xen Support removal from the profitable company on the upstream to force their virtualization solution. But I can't confirm if this is really the issue.

Comment: I am having the same problem with Clear OS Community v6.5.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when I tried to install I had the same problem. using the procedure in xenserver (cli)

xe vm-list

get uuid of your vm

xe vm-param-set uuid=uuid_of_your_virtual_machine platform:viridian=false

I could continue the installation.

Comment: This appears to be related to this bug: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=918239#c13

Comment: +1 The installer for Clear OS Community v6.5.0 succeeded with this work-around.

Answer (score 1):

We had this problem as well. You need to use text mode, or disable/downshift the graphical install during the netboot. 
On your kernel options pass nohz=off highres=off 
See: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=632811